# jQuery : Using buttons generated by a plugin to interact with

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm beginner in jQuery Plugin's coding.

I've coded a plugin to generate a Gantt's calendar but i can't succeed with interacting with it.
The code is too long to be posted so i've coded a sample of what a need in kind of interaction.

Here is a sample code that generate a counter and two buttons to increase or decrease the value of the counter.

So the question is : How can i make the button increase / decrease the counter and of course refresh display.

Thanks,

[EDIT]
  I explain again what i want to do :
  - The buttons are generated by the plugin.
  - When they are clicked, they increase/decrease the value and refresh display
  - I dont want an external action binding.
  - The plugin must be **standalone**

[/EDIT]

```
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="/scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  (function($){
    $.fn.mySample = function() {
      var _myCount = 0;
      this.initialize = function ()
      {
          this.html('<input type="button" value="--">Count : ' + _myCount + '<input type="button" value="++">');
      }

      return this.initialize();
    }
  })(jQuery);

  $(document).ready(
    function()
    {
      $('#myDiv').mySample();
    }
  );
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the code is too long to post here it might be a good idea to make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/) demonstrating your problem.

Comment: You can also use http://codeshare.io/ if your code is too long. But please care: users can modify your code so JSFiddle might be better for that purpose.

Comment: Never heared about JSFiddle, i'll have a look ! The sample resume my problem:  just interact "from the inside" with the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for my first answer :)

So here is your mySample plugin working as a standalone

http://jsfiddle.net/P4p3m/2/

```
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2">
  <title></title>
  <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  (function($){
    $.fn.mySample = function() {
      this._counter = 0; // Your counter

      this.initialize = function (config)
      {
        // Get the context of the outside
        var context = this;

        // Init the -- button
        var inputMinus = document.createElement("input");
        inputMinus.type = "button";
        inputMinus.value = "--";
        $(inputMinus).click(function(){
          context.updateCounter(-1);
        });
        this.append(inputMinus);

        // Init the display
        var spanDisplay = document.createElement("span");
        context.spanDisplay = spanDisplay;
        $(spanDisplay).text(context._counter);
        this.append(spanDisplay);

        // Init the ++ button
        var inputPlus = document.createElement("input");
        inputPlus.type = "button";
        inputPlus.value = "++";
        $(inputPlus).click(function(){
          context.updateCounter(+1);
        });
        this.append(inputPlus);
      }

      // Updating the counter value and the display
      this.updateCounter = function(nbr){
        this._counter += nbr;
        $(this.spanDisplay).html(this._counter);
      };

      // Start the plugin
      return this.initialize();
    }
  })(jQuery);

  $(document).ready(
    function()
    {
      $('#myDiv').mySample();
    }
  );
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Care I use jquery-1.11.0.min.js, so you should modify line 5 to your jquery lib: <script src="/scripts/jquery.js"></script>

Comment: My pleasure ;) Don't hesitate for futher questions

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code to add id's to better identify the buttons and a span to identify where we want to modify the count:

Here's the updated code to reflect your comments, along with the code working in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XMgz4/

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.mySample = function () {
      var _myCount = 0;
      var inputStr = '<input id="decButton" type="button" value="--">'
                   + 'Count : <span id="count">' + _myCount
                   + '</span><input id="incButton" type="button" value="++">';
      this.html(inputStr);

      this.find("#decButton").on("click", function() {
          _myCount --;
          $("#count").text(_myCount);
      });
      this.find("#incButton").on("click", function() {
          _myCount ++;
          $("#count").text(_myCount);
      });
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This can't work, _myCount have a plugin's scope. Not a global. I've copy/paste your code : ReferenceError: _myCount is not defined :-(

Comment: Sorry, it was just an example of what to do to change the count. The second block of code should be included in the plugin with methods like `this.increment`, `this.decrement`.

Comment: Can't see what you mean, could you repost complete code ?

Comment: You shouln't use the find function from jQuery => your plugin can have conflicts with other HTML ID or other plugins

Comment: Using `this.find` won't have any conflicts as long as the plugin itself doesn't have two ids with the same name.  `find` only returns descendants of the element (http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: Thanks for your code dsilver1221. All i wanted is to have sample's and idea's of how to do. It's done ;-)

Comment: Yes dsilver1221 but I someone does

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put the `Count : ' + _myCount + '` inside an element.. like this:

`'Count : <div id="result">' + _myCount + '</div>'`

After that you will create a function to get the value of result.. like this `$('#result').html()`

and increase or decrease the value using onclick event of your inputs... (You must to add class or id for your inputs...)

I will suppose that the id is `btnDecrease` and `btnIncrease`... You will need to do something like this:

```
$('#btnDecrease').on('click', function(){
    $('#result').html(parseInt($('#result').html()) - 1);
});
```

and

```
$('#btnIncrease').on('click', function(){
    $('#result').html(parseInt($('#result').html()) + 1);
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for help, but this is not what i want to do. Your solution is to retreive html's code and increase it. My question was to interact with the plugin by a function inside the plugin and to throw it with the generated button.

Comment: You shouldn't use an ID into a plugin (you can have conflicts).